# Как разобрать псевдокод?

Tags: псевдокод

В книге "алгоритмы построение и анализ" Кормен.

Приводится псевдокод, но не могу найти где дается описание этого псевдокода.
Автор говорит что он похож на языки C, pascal и java.

```
Insertion-Sort(A)
1) for j  <- 2 to length[A]
2)     do key  <- A[j]
3)         >> Вставка элемента A[j] в отсортированную 
           >> последовательность A[1..j - 1]
4)         i <- j - 1
5)         while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6)              do A[i + 1] <- A[i]
7)                   i <- i -1
8)         A[i + 1] <- key
```

1. Знак <- это ведь присваивание?
2. Отступы символизируют вложенность циклов? Строка 8 вложена в строку 2(цикл do)?
3. То есть во 2 строке начинается цикл do который заканчивается на while(строка 5) или do(2) в смысле делай в контесте for(1), а while(6) связана с do(7)? Ведь здесь получается два цикла do и только один раз while.
4. В строке 3 отображается комментарий, описание кода который следует создать или описание следующего за ним кода?
5. Где нибудь есть универсальное описание псевдокода? То есть стандарт что ли? Где не встречается везде по разному пишут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Да, присваивание
2. Да
3. Здесь конструкция do начинает тело цикла. Т.е. есть цикл for <условие> do <тело> и while <условие> do <тело>
4. Да, это комментарий на две строчки к коду ниже
5. Нет, нету, но существует БНФ, с помощью которой можно записывать псевдокоды и языки программирования